# Instalando sem sucesso uma app num tablet Genesis GT-7240

Tags: android, google-maps

Tenho um tablet Genesis GT-7240, cujo versão do Android é 4.1.1, Kernel 3.0.36+.

Meu `manifest.xml` tem

```html
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Eu estou tentando rodar uma aplicação simples, que usa o Google Maps e, por isto, a compilação tem de ser via API Google e não Android.

Compilei o aplicativo, marquei no tablet para aceitar as fontes não confiáveis, copiei a APK para a pasta download do tablet, conforme já fiz centenas de vezes com outros aplicativos.

Entretanto, ao instalar o aplicativo, vem a mensagem

> X App not instaled

e não há explicação de qual erro.

Outros aplicativos que se baseiam em Google Maps também vi que não funcionaram a contento, antes.

Nota: Num outro tablet, agora um Samsung, funciona. E a versão é 3.2.

Comment: Você consegue instalar, ou o tablet tem, o Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A API do Google Maps não é nativa do SO Android, ou seja, não faz parte do core do Android e pode não estar disponível nesse tablet.

Isso ocorre principalmente em modelos que não são homologados pela OHA e Google, e assim por questões legais não podem colocar o Google Maps no dispositivo, e por isso não é possível instalar pois é uma biblioteca essencial para o aplicativo que não está instalado no tablet.

Inclusive esse é o motivo de você conseguir instalar no dispositivo da Samsung, que é homologado e possui o Google Maps.

Comment: Neto Marin, possivelmente você acertou na mosca.

Comment: Obrigado Mauro. Aceite a resposta então como correta :) obrigado, abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu `AndroidManifest.xml` tiver a permissão `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` e o aparelho não tiver GPS (o que parece ser o caso desse tablet), não vai instalar. O motivo é simples: essa permissão é justamente a que disponibiliza o recurso de GPS para os aplicativos e portanto requer um receptor de GPS para funcionar.

Comment: Caro Piovezan, em meu manifest.xml, nas <permission não fiz nenhuma referência ao tipo de 'provider'. Nem Fine e nem Coarse, pois o tutorial não falava nada nisto. E funciona na versão 3.2, num tablet mais avançado, que é o Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui na empresa também utilizo um Tablet da Genesis para desenvolvimento (GT-1230), e percebi que estes aparelhos não contam com vários sensores, já tive problemas tentando baixar apps no Google Play, por falta de sensores (hardware) e não por versão de software, verifique se estes aplicativos baseados em API Google, não necessitam de algum sensor que talvez seu Tablet não tenha disponível.

Obs: pode ser que seja outra coisa, mas pela minha experiência deve ser algum ligado a hardware, e não a software.

Comment: Caro Fernando, estou pensando mesmo nisto, que é um problema de hardware, conforme também opinião do amigo Piovezan, de outra maneira.